# How to create more than one loading spinner in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to create three loading spinners in my Jquery mobile application that will be
showed on my page(in different places) for a while. In my example  when I call function1() I want to have loading spinners in #main-menu div,when I call function2() I want to have loading spinner in .news div and when I call function3() I want to have loading spinner in .some-class div. Here is example of my HTML page:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
    function1();
    function2();
    function3();
   </script>
   </head>

   <body>
<div id="container">
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
                <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <div id="main-menu" >   
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="news">     
            </div>

            <div class="some-class">   
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer">

        </div>

    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

If I use $.mobile.loading('show') it will only show one loading spinner in the middle of page. Is there any way
to create more than one loading spinner? I would really appreciate any tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile doesn't provide you a way to show 3 loaders at a time. You can utilise jQuery Mobile to show a loader in the middle.

I think you are trying to emulate Android UI with loader on ActionBar etc. What you can do is dynamically show and hide a `gif` loader image in the divs.

User jquery [.css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to add and remove background gif to the div

Comment: Thanks I'll try to do with css method and I'll post answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody needs here is how I solved this problem: I've used plugin spin.js
http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/
It's pretty easy to use and you can have multiple loading spinners.